# Not able to scroll down by selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, scrape

I'm trying to scrape a website for an about 2 days, but scrolling down to get more elements is the problem. I've almost checked every javascript code in stackoverflow to do that, but none of them worked.
For example :

- `window.scrollTo(1, 1000)`
- `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);`
- `arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);`

I even used [this](https://csnotes.medium.com/web-scraping-infinite-scrolling-with-selenium-97f820d2e506) article, but it didn't work either.

I checked the network to see if I can find the API to use requests to get more elements, but I couldn't find it.

All I want to do is to get more elements, so is there a way to do that?

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: Update the question with your actual code trials.

Comment: This is the url https://panel.jaryan.net/u/B7SHKNSt/campaign?draftId=24942

Comment: There isn't much code, I just open the page using driver.get and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach to scroll page down:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver.find_element('xpath', '//body').send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked (move_to_element):

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
your_link = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'ClassName')]"
action = ActionChains(driver)
action.move_to_element(your_link).perform()
```